# What synchronization primitives exist in Qt5 that would allow me to wait for a signal to arrive in a single thread?

Tags: c++, synchronization, qt5, signals-slots

In my application I have a need to block execution until a signal arrives (wait for web request to finish). This happens in a non-gui thread.

Looking at the [blocking fortune client example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtnetwork-blockingfortuneclient-example.html) in Qt 5.3 docs, it appears that it uses [waitForConnected()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#waitForConnected) method that is specific to the [QTcpSocket](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html) class, but I am using [QNetworkAccessManager](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) which has no wait methods at all.

I have also read [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556421/blocked-waiting-for-a-asynchronous-qt-signal) that to do this one might want to create a temporary [QEventLoop](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QEventLoop.html), which will block until the events complete. This solution comes with a bunch of warnings that it should not be used in "production code" because of various latent problems that might arrise in corner cases etc.

So. What's a guy to do?

Can I somehow make this work with a QWaitCondition without introducing a second thread? What synchronization primitives exist in Qt5 that would allow me to wait for a signal to arrive in a single thread?

Thanks!

Comment: Qt is designed to be asynchronous, meaning you shouldn't have to block except in a few unusual circumstances (unit tests, for example.)  If you could describe what you're trying to achieve, perhaps someone could suggest a way to accomplish it without blocking.

Comment: That sort of answers the question, there are no primitives for blocking on signals in Qt except starting a temporary event-loop.

Comment: How about making that an answer so we can get this thread out of its missery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt is designed to be [asynchronous](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/signalsandslots.html), meaning you shouldn't have to block except in a few unusual circumstances (unit tests, for example.)

If you could describe what you're trying to achieve, perhaps someone could suggest a way to accomplish it without blocking.

Comment: Unfortunately my case is related to accessing flaky hardware, so there aren't any way around this